# How to call another function from another def():

Tags: python

Hello i want use another function from another **def():** and i tried this:

```
import os
import socket
import uuid
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter

def key_generator(stringId):

    stringId  = uuid.uuid4()

    message_sender()

def message_sender(stringId):

    machine_name = '[' + socket.gethostname() + ']'
     
    webhook = Webhook.from_url("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/881232472644390933/MbAbLqd9G6eGYRO25zaIIrF6hJPNJCJWJm_9JTAiYxBeULevXNNaZJhQHcJSYPRcby89", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
    webhook.send('`|---' + stringId + '---| Key: ' + '|' + 'key' + '|`')

key_generator()
```

it does generate key and sends it via my discord webhook adress. How i can do it correctly?

Comment: You seem to have a very deep misunderstanding on how `stringId` is passed in this context. Can you share how you feel the value of `stringId` is passed to the `message_sender()` function when you haven’t actually provided it as a parameter to your function invocation…?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to message_sender is missing a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the `stringId` variable as an argument to `message_sender`.

Comment: Hello im a new python coder i understanded your comments but i don't know how to do it how i cn do it ?

Comment: Instead of `message_sender()`, write `message_sender(stringId)`.

Comment: hello it already written in code

Comment: Inside the function definition for `key_generator`, when you call `message_sender`, instead of `message_sender()`, write `message_sender(stringId)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the stringId variable as an argument to message_sender.